# Writing sections of a file to two other files

Tags: python, file

So I've got a file which contains combined instances (list of numbers) for a program i'm writing.
I then proceed to put all the lines with '@' to both training and testing files. Now I want to put 28,709 instances to my training file and then the rest of the file's instances to the testing file.

When I do this, with this code:

```
import itertools

# Splits the training and testing instances
# with the newly reduced attributes

training = open('training.txt', 'w')
testing = open('testing.txt', 'w')

linecount = 0

with open('combined.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        if not l.startswith('@'):
            break
        else:
            training.write(l)
            testing.write(l)
            linecount += 1

with open('combined.txt', 'r') as f:
    newcount = 0
    for l in f:
        while(newcount < linecount):
            f.next()
            newcount += 1

        if linecount > (linecount + 28709):
            testing.write(l)
        else:
            training.write(l)
        linecount += 1
    '''# Write 28,709 instances to training set
    for l in itertools.islice(f, linecount, linecount + 28709):
        training.write(l)
    # Write rest of instances to testing set
    for i in xrange(linecount + 28710):
        f.next()
    for l in f:
        testing.write(l)'''
```

.. It doesn't do all the instances to the training set and doesn't output anything testing set. The **original** combined file can be found here (too big to paste here): https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ryankshah/618fde939a54c5eb8642135ab1f4514c/raw/a5a11c0fc301a6724b9af4c413d76b96ffa9859c/combined.txt

**EDIT:** All the @ symbol lines should be in both. Then the first 28709 lines after the last '@' should be in the training file and the rest in the test file

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by what exactly should be in the test and training file. All the @ symbol lines should be in both. Then you want lines without the @ symbol to just be in the test file?

Comment: @AlexF All the @ symbol lines should be in both. Then the first 28709 lines after the last '@' should be in the training file and the rest in the test file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need. I added comments in the code to explain what I changed.

```
# Splits the training and testing instances
# with the newly reduced attributes

training = open('training.txt', 'w')
testing = open('testing.txt', 'w')

linecount = 0

with open('combined.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        if not l.startswith('@'):
            break
        else:
            training.write(l)
            testing.write(l)
        # increment every time to get position of last '@' symbol
        # can't skip lines in between '@'' symbols
        linecount += 1

val = 28709

with open('combined.txt', 'r') as f:
    # skip first n lines up to last '@' symbol
    for _ in range(linecount):
        f.next()

    # write first 28709 lines after last '@' symbol to training file
    new_linecount = 0
    for l in f:
        if new_linecount >= val:
            testing.write(l)
        else:
            training.write(l)
        new_linecount += 1
    '''# Write 28,709 instances to training set
    for l in itertools.islice(f, linecount, linecount + 28709):
        training.write(l)
    # Write rest of instances to testing set
    for i in xrange(linecount + 28710):
        f.next()
    for l in f:
        testing.write(l)'''
```